# Hudson CI: how to extract metrics from a report file

Tags: hudson

I'm using Hudson CI to automate the integration of my FPGA projects. In one of the build steps, I run a logic synthesis tool which produces a plain-text report file. The report contains a few metrics, such as the maximum frequency, which I would like to monitor over time. Here's how the maximum frequency appears in the report:

```
Minimum period: 5.720ns (Maximum Frequency: 174.821MHz)
```

How can I extract and monitor/chart such metrics in Hudson?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered on the Hudson forum: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/452719/1007740/#msg_1007740

The solution is to use the [Plot plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Plot+Plugin).